# Form action not redirecting to proper page in Node JS Express server

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, forms, express

I have a simple EJS app that uses jQuery in the js code to get json data from google custom search API and use the get method to go to `/search` with the query listed as the attribute of `q` the form's code looks like this:

```html
<form action="/search" id="search-form" class="search-form" role="search" method="get">
  <div class="search-logo">
    <svg class="search-logo-svg">
      <use href="#brand"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="search-box">
    <input type="search" class="search-box-input" id="search-input" role="searchbox" name="q" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit" class="search-box-submit" role="button">
      <svg width="20" height="20">
        <use href="#search"></use>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

the jquery code that handles the search looks like this:

```js
var dataWeb;
var dataImg;


$(document).ready(function() {
  var query = getParameterByName('q');
  var start = getParameterByName('start');
  if (start == "") {
    start = 1;
  }
  if (query !== '') {
    $('#search-input').val(query);
    search(query, start);
  }

  $('#search-form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var query = $('#search-input').val();
    search(query, start);
  });
});

function search(query, start) {
  var apiKey = ' example API key ';
  var cx = 'example cx'
  var urlWeb = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' + apiKey + '&cx=' + cx + '&q=' + query + '&start=' + start;
  urlWeb = 'https://nitriaold-2.gtoy118.repl.co/search-test.json';
  var urlImage = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=' + apiKey + '&cx=' + cx + '&searchType=image&q=' + query + '&start=' + start;
  urlImage = 'https://nitriaold-2.gtoy118.repl.co/search-test-image.json'

  $.ajax({
    url: urlWeb,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      showResultsWeb(data.items, data.spelling, data);
      dataWeb = data;
    }
  });

  $.ajax({
    url: urlImage,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      showResultsImage(data.items, data.spelling, data);
      dataImg = data;
    }
  });

  updateURL(query, start);
}

function updateURL(query, start) {
  var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&start=' + start;
  window.history.pushState({ path: url }, '', url);
}
```

The functions that aren't defined in this snippet are defined in the actual code, and the full version can be found here: https://nitria.gtoy118.repl.co. I have confirmed that they work well and are just used to display the results.

The node js code looks like this:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Nitria' });
});
app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  res.render('search');
})
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server started on port ' + port);
});

app.use(express.static('views/src'));

app.post('/display-input', (req, res) => {
  const input = req.body.hello;
  res.render('input', { input });
});
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.get('/input', (req, res) => {
  res.render('input');
});

app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
  const query = req.body.query;
  res.redirect('/search?q=' + query);
});
```

When I run this code, I type in my query to the form and when I submit it, instead of going to `/search?q=hi&start=1` it goes to `/?q=hi&start=1`. When I add `search` into the URL manually, it works fine, so I know that part of the code works fine. I have minimal experience with Express servers, so explanations are helpfull.

Comment: Side note: please remove your apikey from here, and rotate it

Comment: Why two `/search` routes?

Comment: @pierpy That was me expirementing fixes to the problem

Comment: @pierpy what do you mean by "rotate it?"

Comment: Rotate, it's a common word for changing periodically a secret. Now you exposed the key on the whole Internet, so it's better to delete and regenerate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `updateURL` function does exactly that. Does not prepend `/search` to the url.
Try to change relevant code in this way:

```
var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query) + '&start=' + start;
```

Also, your second `app.get('/search')` will never fire, because it's already defined before